# Typesetting Subgroup Lattices in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, tikz-cd, xy-pic, xymatrix

Trying to figure out the easiest way to create a subgroup lattice in LaTeX. Looking to create something like this one for `$D_4$'. [image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The `tikz-cd` package  can do it.

Answer (score 4):

Very easy with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}]
&&D_4\ar[d]\ar[dl]\ar[dr]\\
&\langle r^2,f \rangle \ar[d]\ar[dl]\ar[dr]&\langle r\rangle\ar[d] &\langle r^2,rf\rangle\ar[d]\ar[dl]\ar[dr]\\
\langle f\rangle\ar[rrd]&\langle r^2,f\rangle\ar[rd]&\langle r^2\rangle\ar[d]&\langle rf\rangle\ar[ld]&\langle r^3f\rangle\ar[lld]\\
&&\langle e\rangle
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here there is the version with `xy` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{xymatrix}{
&&D_4\ar@{-}[d]\ar@{-}[dl]\ar@{-}[dr]\\
&\langle r^2,f \rangle \ar@{-}[d]\ar@{-}[dl]\ar@{-}[dr]&\langle r\rangle\ar@{-}[d] &\langle r^2,rf\rangle \ar@{-}[d]\ar@{-}[dl]\ar@{-}[dr]\\
\langle f\rangle\ar@{-}[rrd]&\langle r^2,f\rangle\ar@{-}[rd]&\langle r^2\rangle\ar@{-}[d]&\langle rf\rangle\ar@{-}[ld]&\langle r^3f\rangle\ar@{-}[lld]\\
&&\langle e\rangle}
\end{xymatrix}
\end{document}
```

[image]